# Splitting texts python

Tags: python

thanks for answering my questions, I just want to clarify what I was asking.
I'm trying to split the following string using str.split('+'), I'm reading in the strings from a text file:

```
['\A'+'ABBOTT\s|\s'+'ABBOTT\s|\s'+'ABBOTT$|\A'+'ABBOTT LABORATORIES\s|\s'+'ABBOTT LABORATORIES\s|\s'+'ABBOTT LABORATORIES$']
```

the desired results would be:

```
['\A'+'ABBOTT\s|\s', 'ABBOTT\s|\s', 'ABBOTT$|\A', 'ABBOTT LABORATORIES\s|\s', 'ABBOTT LABORATORIES\s|\s', 'ABBOTT LABORATORIES$']
```

But instead I'm getting: 
["'\A'", "'ABBOTT\s|\s'", "'ABBOTT\s|\s'", "'ABBOTT$|\A'", "'ABBOTT LABORATORIES\s|\s'", "'ABBOTT LABORATORIES\s|\s'", "'ABBOTT LABORATORIES$'"]

But I can't get the \ to stay as a single, after splitting
Thanks again!!!

Comment: That's just its representation.  Try printing it.  Take a look at ths question: [How to replace a double backslash with a single backslash in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752485/how-to-replace-a-double-backslash-with-a-single-backslash-in-python)

Comment: some things to note: if possible provide working source code, to make your problem reproducible for others; let the number of problems per question approach one where possible; don't change the main problem of your question, submit a new one when there are follow-up problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you print the array directly it will look as if the value of the first entry is `['\\A'`, this is also how the value should be written when dealing with it in your script.

That is because print in that context will wrap the string inside `""` and escape characters such as `\` inside (turning them into `\\` in the printed string).

```
"['\\A'+'ABBOTT\\s|\\s'+'ABBOTT\\s|\\s'+'ABBOTT$|\\A'+'ABBOTT LABORATORIES\\s|\\s'+'ABBOTT LABORATORIES\\s|\\s'+'ABBOTT LABORATORIES$']"
```

---

The "real" value of your string isn't like that.

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Aug 22 2011, 13:53:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin

>>> print "['\\A'+'ABBOTT\\s|\\s'+'ABBOTT LABORATORIES$']".split ('+')
["['\\A'", "'ABBOTT\\s|\\s'", "'ABBOTT LABORATORIES$']"]

>>> print "['\\A'+'ABBOTT\\s|\\s'+'ABBOTT LABORATORIES$']".split ('+')[0]
['\A'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer,
I just tried that, but I get

["'\\\\A'", "'ABBOTT\\\\s|\\\\s'", "'ABBOTT\\\\s|\\\\s'", "'ABBOTT$|\\\\A'", "'ABBOTT LABORATORIES\\\\s|\\\\s'", "'ABBOTT LABORATORIES\\\\s|\\\\s'", "'ABBOTT LABORATORIES$'"]

I think the problem is that I'm reading in the line from a text file, and I'm partitioning on a variable that has the string stored.  
thanks again!!!

Comment: Hi again, 
I think if there is a way to remove the "" that is currently wrapping my imported text, the split should work fine.  Any advice??? 
thanks!!!!

Comment: @Heatherm You could use `'string'` instead of `""` but then you will have to escape the `'` present in your string.

Comment: @HeaterM Also, please mark the answer as accepted since your original question has been answered, this will mark the problem as solved, thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your answer.  I think I was not clear enough in my questions before.  (sry, my first time posting, I was trying to simply my question)

I import the following line from a .txt file: 
(line='\A'+'ABBOTT\s|\s'+'ABBOTT\s|\s'+'ABBOTT$|\A'+'ABBOTT LABORATORIES\s|\s'+'ABBOTT LABORATORIES\s|\s'+'ABBOTT LABORATORIES$')

Iwant the following two statements to produce the same results:
re.compile(line, re.I+re.M);
re.compile('\A'+'ABBOTT\s|\s'+'ABBOTT\s|\s'+'ABBOTT$|\A'+'ABBOTT LABORATORIES\s|\s'+'ABBOTT LABORATORIES\s|\s'+'ABBOTT LABORATORIES$', re.I+re.M);

Comment: I'm getting very different results.  
Thanks again, 
@moooeeeep I hope you don't mind looking at this again :)