# Remove one \ from string

Tags: string, python-3.x

I have a string:

```
C:\\tmp\\files\\file.xxx
```

How do I remove only one `\`?

End results:

```
C:\tmp\files\file.xxx
```

Comment: why ? looks like correct path

Comment: but if really want use str.replace() method

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752485/how-to-replace-a-double-backslash-with-a-single-backslash-in-python

Comment: Are you sure you have double `'\\'` ?  It could be just how the debugger shows it to you...

Comment: Please post code since there is some ambiguity in what you're asking.

Comment: @Andy is right, please paste some code

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [Python’s os.path module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)

Though if you would like to replace `\\` with `\`, please do something like,

```
str = "C:\\tmp\\files\\file.xxx";
print str;
```

Output of above code will be,

```
C:\tmp\files\file.xxx
```

I've tested this code over [here](https://www.jdoodle.com/python-programming-online) and it is working.