# Replace double backslash with backslash

Tags: python

I have this string:
`feed_\\d{6}.txt.gz`
and I need to replace the double backslash with a single backslash. I have looked at other answers (including [How to replace a double backslash with a single backslash in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752485/how-to-replace-a-double-backslash-with-a-single-backslash-in-python)) but they haven't helped.

Here are things that don't work

```py
mystr = 'feed_\\d{6}.txt.gz'
mystr.replace('\\', '\')
# invalid syntax. string is unterminated.
```

---

```py
mystr.replace('\\\\', '\\')
#returns the original string
```

---

```py
import codecs
codecs.escape_decode(mystr)
# returns a tuple ('feed_\\d{6}.txt.gz', 17)
# Got this from the aforementioned other thread but it doesn't 
# actually explain how to use it
```

I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide an example string that fails with your attempts?

Comment: `'feed_\\d{6}.txt.gz'` does not contain two backslashes. It contains one backslash. It _looks_ like two backslashes in string literal form or when it's displayed in a REPL, because that's how a backslash is represented via `repr`. But any logic that inspects individual characters of the string will only see one backslash. Similarly, `print('feed_\\d{6}.txt.gz')` will display `feed_\d{6}.txt.gz`.